# .NET Core Web API routes returning 404 only on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, self-contained

If I build my .NET Core app from the solution directory on my windows dev machine like so:

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release --output \myproject --self-contained --runtime win7-x64
```

I can run this and hit my endpoint `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login`, no worries.

I do an almost identical publish to an ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine:

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release --output /ubuntu-myproject --self-contained --runtime ubuntu-x64
```

...copy the files up to the folder, set the proper project file to executable and run it, it starts listening on localhost:5000 just the same.  Static pages (like my basic index.html) serve... but all my api endpoints are returning 404's.  I'm scratching my head as to why this would be.  There doesn't seem to be any error messages or anything, it's like the routes are just not registered or something.

Can someone clue me in as to why this might be the case?

This was built with .NET Core SDK 2.1.302.

**UPDATE**

I set the logging to debug and used a route that is known to be working everywhere but this linux machine: `GET /api/groups`.  I called this from the command line window on the linux machine:

```
curl -I  http://localhost:5000/api/groups
```

my response was as such:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 
Date: Wed, 01 Aug 2018 02:15:48 GMT 
Server: Kestrel
```

my log file had the following event info:

```
2018/08/01 02:15:49.241|INFO|Request starting HTTP/1.1 HEAD http://localhost:5000/api/groups   |Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|Protocol=HTTP/1.1, Method=HEAD, ContentType=, ContentLength=, Scheme=http, Host=localhost:5000, PathBase=, Path=/api/groups, QueryString=, EventId_Id=1, EventId_Name=, EventId=1
2018/08/01 02:15:49.535|INFO|Request finished in 292.2005ms 404  |Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost|ElapsedMilliseconds=292.2005, StatusCode=404, ContentType=, EventId_Id=2, EventId_Name=, EventId=2
```

Comment: How are you using and running .NET on Linux?

Comment: @Rob it's a .NET Core web application, self-contained with Kestrel.

Comment: Have you tried it with a different runtime e.g. `ubuntu.18.04`? I had problems using a 'base' runtime but when I used a specific one it worked fine. [The latest list of supported runtimes are here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/runtime.json)

Comment: Try logging to Syslog with [Syslog.Framework.Logging](https://github.com/mguinness/syslog-framework-logging) and see if additional information is provided.

Comment: @SimplyGed I was not aware that runtime was available; I'll try that out.

Comment: @MarkG I'll also see if that gives me any more info.

Comment: @SimplyGed that does not appear to be a valid runtime target?

Comment: @SimplyGed I tried it with the ubuntu 18.04 x64 runtime, I still have the same problem.

Comment: @MarkG I have NLog wired up.  I set the log level to debug and all that's coming out is a 404.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs You don't see anything like "Request successfully matched the route"?  What exactly does show?

Comment: @MarkG I updated my post with a breakdown of what I'm seeing.

Comment: Can you open next issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/194

Comment: @Mixim I'm not understanding what you're asking?  Are you suggesting I open a ticket or suggesting that this ticket resolution may solve my problem?  I'm not using a MapWhen... and it seems like that would be a problem regardless of what machine it was running on.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Any reason you're using option `-I` in curl?  Won't you need `HttpHead` in addition to `HttpGet` attribute?

Comment: @MarkG you've gone beyond my knowledge of curl; I just googled how to check a RESTful endpoint.  I would expect, however, missing appropriate header information that I would get a 401 or 403 instead of a 404.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Try curl w/o `-I` option.  Are you using convention or attribute based routing?  Can you share your config?

Comment: @MarkG I am using attribute-based routing; My configuration is actually not especially easy to share; each configured component is in a separate class to keep the startup class moderately short and clean.

Comment: I will say that my curl tests were secondary, after trying to figure out why my reverse proxy was returning 404's, so I don't think it's a problem with the way I'm using curl, but I'll experiment and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here was actually 2 things.  As @MarkG suggested, I was being led astray by my incorrect assumption of how to test an API endpoint with `curl`.  I should not have used the `-I` parameter, it was sending the wrong request, hence I got a 404... in other words, instead of sending a `GET /api/groups` request, I was sending a `HEAD /api/groups`... which was not a defined route, and therefore *should* return a 404.

The second problem was that my nginx proxy was not properly configured, so externally all my /api/ endpoints were returning 404 as well, for a different reason.  In combination with my bad curl requests, it seemed that nginx *was* properly configured, and my api service was simply returning 404's for everything... when in fact it was just me messing up at multiple levels.

Comment: I know it's been awhile, but could you give a better explanation of what you did to solve this? I am in the same boat right now and unfortunately your explanation above is a little light on exact details.

Comment: @JeffTurner well, the main thing I did was fix my nginx settings.  It's not something that fits into a comment, but there are some tutorials out there on how to do it.